# Approximations in article on phonon-assisted emission

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, phonons

I am trying to reproduce the calculations from an old article by J.J. Hopfield (J. Phys. Chem. Solids, vol.10, pp.110-119 (1959) - A theory of edge emission phenomena in CdS, ZnS and ZnO - found [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-3697(59)90064-2)). In the fourth section "The systematics of edge emission", he starts to calculate the probabilities of photon emission with the simultaneous emission of $n$ phonons.

Here he employs an approximation for the thermal spread of the hole in $k$-space, which I assume comes from the Heisenberg uncertainty principle: $k_0=\sqrt{k_B T m/2\hbar^2}$, where the spread in real space is given by the fundamental length scale for a polaron $r=\sqrt{\hbar/2m\omega}$, and using $k_B T$ instead of $\hbar\omega$.

Later, after stating that $W_1$, the transition probability with the emission of 1 phonon is simply $W_0$ multiplied by the Huang-Rhys factor ($\sum|f(q)|^2$, for $q$ smaller than the thermal spread of the hole), there is another approximation which I cannot understand no matter how much I think about it: $W_1=W_0N\sqrt{k_BT/\hbar\omega}$, using a certain approximation for $f(q)$ (which I also don't understand).

To me, it looks as if the sum over $|f(q)|^2$ is approximated as $N\sqrt{k_BT/\hbar\omega}$, and I simply can't figure out how that happens.
If anyone has some insight into these approximations, it would help me immensely. Thank you!

Claudiu